# How do you link the STDOUT of node.js and STDIN of python in NW.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, nw.js

I have been trying to code a python child process in NW.js, I used the code from https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/ It works in vanilla node, but not in NW.js, is this possible, or just in vanilla?

Comment: What does not working mean? What error do you get? Command not found?

Answer (score 0):

NW.js can spawn child processes, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297460/node-webkit-equivalent-for-sinatra). You should post relevant error messages. Just guessing, when you run the code in the different environments, the `PWD` might be different. So try using an absolute path, e.g. calling

```
py = spawn('/usr/bin/python', ['compute_input.py'])
```

or

```
 py = spawn('/usr/local/bin/python', ['compute_input.py'])
```

where the exact path is determined by whatever you get from running `which python`.